# No speaker sound, Ubuntu 20.04 on a MSI B450 TOMAHAWK MAX II motherboard

Tags: drivers, sound, realtek, msi

I installed the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my PC, finally decided to not use Windows anymore! :)
Anyhow, everything works just fine except one thing. I am not able to get any sound at all from the built in soundcard on my motherboard. I'm using the MSI B450 TOMAHAWK MAX II MB that looks like it's a Realtek® ALC892/ALC897 Codec support. Unsure of what chip it actually is. I have looked at other articles but have not been able to resolve it. Any clues? Below are some dumps, but I am too much of a noob to know what to do.

```
hwinfo --sound
30: PCI 2600.1: 0403 Audio device                               
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: LpWl.BsDjMSXwss7
  Parent ID: w+J7.V4+oF1N0NW1
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:26:00.1
  SysFS BusID: 0000:26:00.1
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "nVidia Audio device"
  Vendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x10fa 
  SubVendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  SubDevice: pci 0x1f82 
  Revision: 0xa1
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xf7080000-0xf7083fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 94 (205738 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v000010DEd000010FAsv000010DEsd00001F82bc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #7 (PCI bridge)

32: PCI 2800.4: 0403 Audio device
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: IVOY.SAFhJbl9HQA
  Parent ID: JZZT.iY9fDxfULYC
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:28:00.4
  SysFS BusID: 0000:28:00.4
  Hardware Class: sound
  Model: "AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller"
  Vendor: pci 0x1022 "AMD"
  Device: pci 0x1487 "Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1462 "Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI]"
  SubDevice: pci 0xec02 
  Driver: "snd_hda_intel"
  Driver Modules: "snd_hda_intel"
  Memory Range: 0xf7400000-0xf7407fff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 96 (318467 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v00001022d00001487sv00001462sd0000EC02bc04sc03i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: snd_hda_intel is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe snd_hda_intel"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #27 (PCI bridge)
```

```
pacmd list-cards
3 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_28_00.4>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 23
    properties:
        alsa.card = "2"
        alsa.card_name = "HD-Audio Generic"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HD-Audio Generic at 0xf7400000 irq 96"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:28:00.4"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:28:00.4/sound/card2"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "1022"
        device.vendor.name = "Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]"
        device.product.id = "1487"
        device.product.name = "Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller"
        device.string = "2"
        device.description = "Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 32833, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6500, available: no)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6565, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-21: Analog Surround 2.1 Output (priority 1300, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 2.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1365, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-40: Analog Surround 4.0 Output (priority 1200, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1265, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-41: Analog Surround 4.1 Output (priority 1300, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1365, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-50: Analog Surround 5.0 Output (priority 1200, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1265, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-51: Analog Surround 5.1 Output (priority 1300, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1365, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-71: Analog Surround 7.1 Output (priority 1200, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 7.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1265, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_28_00.4.analog-stereo/#1: Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_28_00.4.analog-stereo.monitor/#1: Monitor of Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo
        alsa_input.pci-0000_28_00.4.analog-stereo/#2: Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo
    ports:
        analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority 8500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-rear-mic: Rear Microphone (priority 8200, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-linein: Line In (priority 8100, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    index: 1
    name: <alsa_card.usb-046d_C922_Pro_Stream_Webcam_E927BFCF-02>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 24
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "C922 Pro Stream Webcam"
        alsa.long_card_name = "C922 Pro Stream Webcam at usb-0000:03:00.0-8, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:03:00.0-usb-0:8:1.2"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.2/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-046d_C922_Pro_Stream_Webcam_E927BFCF-02"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "046d"
        device.vendor.name = "Logitech, Inc."
        device.product.id = "085c"
        device.product.name = "C922 Pro Stream Webcam"
        device.serial = "046d_C922_Pro_Stream_Webcam_E927BFCF"
        device.form_factor = "webcam"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "C922 Pro Stream Webcam"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "camera-web-usb"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 65, available: unknown)
        input:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (priority 55, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <input:analog-stereo>
    sources:
        alsa_input.usb-046d_C922_Pro_Stream_Webcam_E927BFCF-02.analog-stereo/#3: C922 Pro Stream Webcam Analog Stereo
    ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        iec958-stereo-input: Digital Input (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                
    index: 2
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_26_00.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 25
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xf7080000 irq 94"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:26:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:26:00.1/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "10fa"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "HDA NVidia"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 38668, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra3: Digital Stereo (HDMI 4) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra3: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra3: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 4) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra4: Digital Stereo (HDMI 5) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra4: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra4: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 5) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra5: Digital Stereo (HDMI 6) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra5: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 6) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra5: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 6) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:hdmi-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_26_00.1.hdmi-stereo/#92: HDA NVidia Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_26_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor/#94: Monitor of HDA NVidia Digital Stereo (HDMI)
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                device.product.name = "Mi Monitor
  "
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-3: HDMI / DisplayPort 4 (priority 5600, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-4: HDMI / DisplayPort 5 (priority 5500, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-5: HDMI / DisplayPort 6 (priority 5400, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

```
lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Root Complex
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Starship/Matisse Root Complex
    Flags: fast devsel

00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse IOMMU
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Starship/Matisse IOMMU
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 25
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel

00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: f7900000-f79fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=25, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000f000-0000ffff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: f7500000-f76fffff [size=2M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel

00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel

00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse GPP Bridge (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=26, subordinate=26, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: f6000000-f70fffff [size=17M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0000000-00000000f1ffffff [size=288M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel

00:05.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel

00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel

00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B] (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=27, subordinate=27, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
    Flags: fast devsel

00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B] (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 31
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=28, subordinate=28, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: f7200000-f74fffff [size=3M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B] (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=30, subordinate=30, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: f7800000-f78fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:08.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to bus[E:B] (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 33
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=31, subordinate=31, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: f7700000-f77fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 61)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] FCH SMBus Controller
    Flags: 66MHz, medium devsel
    Kernel driver in use: piix4_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_piix4, sp5100_tco

00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] FCH LPC Bridge
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0

00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 0
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 1
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 2
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 3
    Flags: fast devsel
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
    Kernel modules: k10temp

00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 4
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 5
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 6
    Flags: fast devsel

00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse Device 24: Function 7
    Flags: fast devsel

01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983 (prog-if 02 [NVM Express])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 41, NUMA node 0
    Memory at f7900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme

03:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset USB 3.1 XHCI Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. 400 Series Chipset USB 3.1 XHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 80
    Memory at f76a0000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

03:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset SATA Controller (rev 01) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ASMedia Technology Inc. 400 Series Chipset SATA Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
    Memory at f7680000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Expansion ROM at f7600000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

03:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Bridge (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
    Bus: primary=03, secondary=20, subordinate=25, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000f000-0000ffff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: f7500000-f75fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

20:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 36
    Bus: primary=20, secondary=21, subordinate=21, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

20:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 38
    Bus: primary=20, secondary=22, subordinate=22, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000f000-0000ffff [size=4K]
    Memory behind bridge: f7500000-f75fffff [size=1M]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

20:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 39
    Bus: primary=20, secondary=25, subordinate=25, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: [disabled]
    Memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

22:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 37
    I/O ports at f000 [size=256]
    Memory at f7504000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at f7500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

26:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117 [GeForce GTX 1650] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation TU117 [GeForce GTX 1650]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 97
    Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

26:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10fa (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f82
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 94
    Memory at f7080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

27:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Starship/Matisse PCIe Dummy Function
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: <access denied>

28:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Starship/Matisse Reserved SPP
    Flags: fast devsel
    Capabilities: <access denied>

28:00.1 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse Cryptographic Coprocessor PSPCPP
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Starship/Matisse Cryptographic Coprocessor PSPCPP
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 90
    Memory at f7300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Memory at f7408000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ccp
    Kernel modules: ccp

28:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Matisse USB 3.0 Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 81
    Memory at f7200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci

28:00.4 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 96
    Memory at f7400000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

30:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    Memory at f7800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

31:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at f7700000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
```

Comment: Can you try connecting the speaker to the monitor/tv? I had the same problem in Pop OS and that solved my problem.

Comment: have you examined your sound settings in `Settings Sound Output` You should be able to set `Speakers - Built-in Audio` from the drop-down menu and then click on Test

Comment: In the Settings - Sound - Output device I only have my BT headset and the HDMI monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, I had to do an unortodox approach, my monitor does not have speakers, so I got a cheap HDMI Audio splitter box, connected the HDMI output from the motherboard to the splitter box, connected HDMI out from the box to the Monitor, and final step connected the speakers to the Audio out of the splitter box, and worked like a charm.

Spent days trying every trick on the web to solve it by software, but never worked, Ubuntu never recognized the card and "Sound System Settings" always saying "DUMMY OUTPUT", drove me nuts...

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Can you explain how your situation is similar to the original poster's? Do you have the same motherboard? The same audio card?

Comment: Also, it looks like your solution was to avoid the audio card entirely, and to grab audio from the graphics integrated into the motherboard instead. Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Yup, I do have the Tomahwak B450 motherboard, and search for Ubuntu drivers to no avail, fiddle with 'option' parameter in config files like crazy and Ubuntu never recognized the Audio,  thats why I had move in a different direction.

Comment: Yes, its more a circumvention than a solution, and you got it right I did avoid it because its of no use if Ubuntu is not able to recognize the motherboard audio card.